# Can Facebook username and email store in wp-users for WordPress

Tags: android, wordpress, localhost

When user login into the app with Facebook login, the information of Facebook like username and email can store in wp-user for WordOress or not? If so, do I need to write it in php?

Comment: Yaah! You can do with creating API from wordpress and you can pass data from Android to WP using this API.

Comment: How to create the API, sorry , I am not clear with API

Comment: You are not familier with WP [Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

Comment: Is any effect because my app is develop by android studio

Comment: nope first develop your API using wordpress. may be this [tutorial may help you](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)